# Sort Array in assending order..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

Sorry for asking silly question..

I have an array with class objects like:

```
Class User {
     NSString *firstName, *LastName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retail) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retail) NSString *LastName;
```

I am creating object of this class and adding it in NSMutableArray.

Now I want to sort this array by the first name.. Any idea please.

Can I use NSSortDescriptor for sorting this array or I have to use my custom logic.

I had done this thing earlier but now I forgot this and don't have source code for that right now...

Please help me..
Thanks

`EDIT:` I got few kind replies and I tried but not working. I am parsing JSON so there will be unknown number of objects in myArray. So I used :

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

and

```
 NSMutableArray *tempArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

but nothing worked..

`Edit 2`

Here is the description:
Array

```
    "<User: 0xa3f13c0>",
    "<User: 0xa3f1410>",
    "<User: 0xa3f1450>",
    "<User: 0xa3f1490>"
```

Sorted Array

```
"<User: 0xa3f13c0>",
"<User: 0xa3f1410>",
"<User: 0xa3f1490>",
"<User: 0xa3f1450>"
```

In for Loop:
Array

```
John
abc
test
qwertg
```

Sorted Array

```
John
abc
test
qwertg
```

Comment: Could you post the NSLog output of both arrays pre and post sorting? I'd add a description override in the User class before doing that, should look something like   

 -(NSString *)description { return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Firstname - %@", self.firstName];}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're targeting iOS4+ then you can use `sortUsingComparator:` method:

```
[yourArray sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){

        User* u1 = (User*)obj1;
        User* u2 = (User*)obj2;
        return [u1.firstName compare:u2.firstName];
    }];
```

**Edit:** As compare method takes into account character case you may need to use `caseInsensitiveCompare:` method instead of it:

```
[yourArray sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2){

        User* u1 = (User*)obj1;
        User* u2 = (User*)obj2;
        return [u1.firstName caseInsensitiveCompare:u2.firstName];
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir `caseInsensitiveCompare work like a charm.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can make that shorter: `^(User* u1, User* u2) { return [u1.firstName caseInsensitiveCompare:u2.firstName]; }`

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the cleanest way to do what you're looking for:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

A fun way to sort arrays is using code blocks, if you don't need pre ios4 backwards compatibility though

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingComparator:
^(id a, id b) 
{
    User *userA = (User *)a;
    User *userB = (User *)b;
    return [userA.firstName compare:userB.firstName]; 
}];
```

This will allow you to stick some additional logic there in case you'll want to use additional or other sorting conditions in the future.

Comment: If you want additional logic without using blocks you can use sortUsingSelector:.

Comment: I am alread using the first way given by you but it is not sorting my data.

Comment: @Kapil Choubisa are you using sortUsingX or sortedArrayUsingX?

Comment: yes, I had updated my question.. In that I had posted code what I am using.. Same way I had used the Comparator too..